# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined - in ionic 5. I not sure how to fix this.

In My HTML file

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="con-txt" >Document No.</ion-col>
  <ion-col class="con2-txt">{{showDocumentNoBasedOnPriority()}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

In my TS file.

```js
showDocumentNoBasedOnPriority() {
  let documentNoList: any;
  if (this.patientDetails.documents) {
    documentNoList = this.patientDetails.documents;
    let priorityCodes: { [id: string]: number } = {};
    priorityCodes.ID = 0;
    priorityCodes.PP = 1;
    priorityCodes.WP = 2;
    priorityCodes.FREE = 3;
    priorityCodes.X2 = 4;
    priorityCodes.X1 = 5;
    let results = documentNoList.sort((first, second) => {
      return priorityCodes[first.code] - priorityCodes[second.code];
    });
    return results[0].value;
  } else {
    return '-';
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```js
this.api.getPatientData(this.branchId, this.prnNumber)
  .subscribe((patientData) => { 
    console.log('INFO: Patient Data -> ', patientData); 
    if (patientData) { 
      this.patientDetails = patientData; 
      console.log(this.patientDetails); 
      this.loading.dismiss(); 
    } else { 
      console.log('No Patient Records '); 
      this.loading.dismiss(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how `this.patientDetails` is initialised with data?

Comment: this.api.getPatientData(this.branchId , this.prnNumber).subscribe((patientData) => {
           console.log('INFO: Patient Data -> ', patientData);
           if (patientData) {
             this.patientDetails = patientData;
             console.log(  );
             this.loading.dismiss();
           } else {
             console.log('No Patient Records ');
             this.loading.dismiss();
           }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by the asyncronous data. The `patientData` is not set directly, but your function `showDocumentNoBasedOnPriority` checks for it immediately. So when you try `this.patientDetails.documents`, the `this.patientDetails` is not filled with data from your `getPatientData()` and returns undefined.

A better approach would be to trigger your function after your receive the data.

```js
documentNumber: string;

ionViewWillEnter() {
  // when we enter the page, the `getPatientData` function is called
  this.getPatientData();
}

getPatientData() {
  this.api.getPatientData(this.branchId, this.prnNumber)
    .subscribe((patientData: object) => { 
      // If your check for patientData and it returns a empty object, this will still
      // pass. An empty object is truthy in JS. You can surpass this by checking if
      // the object is filled with more than 0 keys.
      if (Object.keys(patientData).length > 0) {
        this.patientDetails = patientData; 
        // now we trigger the function when it matters
        this.showDocumentNoBasedOnPriority();
      } else {
        // when no records are found, the variable is set to '-'
        this.documentNumber = '-';
      }

      this.loading.dismiss(); 
  }
}

showDocumentNoBasedOnPriority() {
  let documentNoList: any;
  if (this.patientDetails.documents) {
    documentNoList = this.patientDetails.documents;
    let priorityCodes: { [id: string]: number } = {};
    priorityCodes.ID = 0;
    priorityCodes.PP = 1;
    priorityCodes.WP = 2;
    priorityCodes.FREE = 3;
    priorityCodes.X2 = 4;
    priorityCodes.X1 = 5;
    let results = documentNoList.sort((first, second) => {
      return priorityCodes[first.code] - priorityCodes[second.code];
    });

    this.documentNumber = results[0].value;
  } else {
    this.documentNumber = '-';
  }
}
```

Display the `documentNumber`. You can always change when or where you want to update the `documentNumber` variable in the code above.

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="con-txt" >Document No.</ion-col>
  <ion-col class="con2-txt">{{ documentNumber }}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Happy to help! You can always accept the answer to 'close' the question ;)